How to position badge in a tab in Android Material 3
I have a tab layout with tab names only (no icons). I want to position a badge in a tab like in the documentation for Material 3 - aligned to the end of the label text

https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/specs
What I get when using getOrCreateBadge on a non-icon tab by default is:

The only available non-deprecated badgeGravities are TOP_START and TOP_END, I would expect there to be a gravity END to match documentation.
I also tried moving the badge with horizontalOffset and verticalOffset. I can move it to the right with negative horizontal offset, but moving it down with vertical offset doesn't work. Regardless, it's not an ideal option.

Please add relevant code. How do you expect someone to help you, without that? People don't memorise code

Refer this file which will provide you the solution for the same :- https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable.java This provides functionality like setHorizontalOffset with or without text and same for the setVerticalOffset with and without text. Starting from line number 868.
